# Google chart design is distubing while it switch to another tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, charts

when i click on view details all data is coming properly but when i click on another tab view details its content overlap or moving right.

[Working Fine Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c63oQ.png)

[Image of chart not working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNsdj.png)

My HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active accepted-btn"><a href="#internaljobs" id="getinternaljobres" data-toggle="tab">INTERNAL JOBS </a></li>
    <?PHP IF($_SESSION['user_type']!= "corporate") {?>
        <li class="not-responed-btn"><a href="#externaljobs" id="getexternaljobres" data-toggle="tab">EXTERNAL JOBS</a></li>
    <?PHP } ?>
</ul>
```

Function of google chart

```
<td><button id="" onClick="getJobDetails(<?php echo $JobResults['id_job']; ?> , 2)"  class="btn btn-s-lg btn-dark btn-rounded text-center ">View Details</button></td>
```

java script code here:

```
function getJobDetails(jobID, id) {
  $("#showReInviteMessage").hide();
  $("#showReInviteStudentsMessage").hide();
  $("#exportInternalJobReport").hide();
  $("#exportExternalJobReport").hide();
  $('#GroupDiscussionForExternalJob').hide();
  $('#PersonalInterViewForExternalJob').hide();
  $.ajax({
        url: "job-controller.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          'action': 'viewjob',
          'JobId': +jobID,
          'intextid': +id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            /*College Pie Chart starts here*/
            google.charts.load("current", {
              packages: ["corechart"]
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartCollegeInvitation);

            function drawChartCollegeInvitation() {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Invites', 'Count'],
                ['YES', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['yes'])],
                ['NO', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['no'])],
                ['Maybe', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['noresponse'])]
              ]);
              var options = {
                'width': 250,
                'height': 250,
                'legend': 'bottom',
                colors: ['green', 'red', '#0061ff'],
                pieHole: 0.3,
                // title: 'Job ID '+response['jobData']['id_job']+' Invitation Status'
                title: 'Total Colleges  Invitied ' + parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['toatalinvites']) + '.'
              };
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('collegeInvitationpiechart'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
/*College Pie Chart ends here*/
```

Comment: this is the result of drawing a chart when it's container is hidden -- also, when donut chart value is 100%, change `pieSliceTextStyle` color in order to see value, default is white (or change `chartArea.backgroundColor`)...

Comment: But the problem is not a color its overlapping chart data,i want data should  be in proper manner, when i click first time its coming properly but when click view details button on another tab its data shows like this as mentioned in chart image above

Comment: can you please answer how to change that color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending this chart from js before appending clear the existing one i hope it should work, nothing seems wrong in your code. make sure you should new regenerate for that periculat pie chart.

```
 /*College Pie Chart starts here*/
            google.charts.load("current", {
              packages: ["corechart"]
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartCollegeInvitation);

            function drawChartCollegeInvitation() {
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Invites', 'Count'],
                ['YES', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['yes'])],
                ['NO', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['no'])],
                ['Maybe', parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['noresponse'])]
              ]);
              var options = {
                'width': 250,
                'height': 250,
                'legend': 'bottom',
                colors: ['green', 'red', '#0061ff'],
                pieHole: 0.3,
                // title: 'Job ID '+response['jobData']['id_job']+' Invitation Status'
                title: 'Total Colleges  Invitied ' + parseInt(response['JobInvitationstatus']['toatalinvites']) + '.'
              };
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('collegeInvitationpiechart'));
              chart.draw(data, options);
            }
/*College Pie Chart ends here*/
```